# Three people have been exposed to a certain illness. Once exposed, a person has a 50-50 chance of actually becoming ill.

Tags: probability

**Three people have been exposed to a certain illness. Once exposed, a person has a 50-50 chance of actually becoming ill.**

a) What is the probability that exactly one of the people becomes ill?

I am a bit unsure, how to solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ represent the state of becoming ill. Thus, $X \sim \text{Binomial}(3,0.5)$. Then,

$$ P(X = 1) = {3 \choose 1}0.5^1\cdot 0.5^2 = 0.375 \to 37.5\%$$

Comment: Why do you say 3/1? and why do you multiple three times with 0,5?

Comment: That's the binomial coefficient, not the fraction $\frac{3}{1}$. For a binomial random variable, the probability of $k$ successes in $n$ trials with probability of success $p$ is is $P(X = k) = {n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$. A "success" here is someone becoming ill.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient